# Explanation of the below graph

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

This was the slide that our professor displayed in class regarding the closing of a capacitive circuit.

[image]

Why is the amplitude(after a certain while) different in both cases? Shouldn't it be the same either ways?

Edit: Haha, I just realized from the answers that I was reading the wrong scale. Thanks though.

Comment: That's what the answers are for! Please accept one of them to indicate that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be the same either ways?

It is.

Notice that the current Y-scale is on the right of the graph and it has changed to accommodate the transient in the lower chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The amplitudes are the same.  The scale on the current axis is different